# getelementsbyname (in an Ajax html response) when I have a partial name. 

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-parsing

I'm stuck in the corners of jQuery universe and could sure use some help.

In short, I make an Ajax call using jQuery (GET) and get a XHTML page as a response. In the response (which includes the `<html>` ,`<head>` and `<body>` tags amongst other things) there is an input element for which I only know part of the name. I need to get the value of this hidden input field which comes along with the response.

p.s. I have no control over what the html response would look like so I can't reformat it.
These files need to be in a folder that contains jQuery.js (latest version today)

This is what I've come up with so far.

Page1.html (makes Ajax call and gets page2.html in response)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <title>runthis</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>

        <script tyle="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
                $('input').click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                                type : "GET",
                                url : 'page2.html',
                                dataType : "html",
                                success: function(data) {
                                    alert($(data).filter('input[name*="test"]').value);
                                },
                                error : function() {
                                        alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
                                }
                        });
                });
        });
        </script

</head>
<body>
        <input type="button" value="load" />
</body>
</html>
```

Page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
        <title>TiTlE</title>

</head>
<body>
        <input type="hidden" name="1-test" value="123" />
        <input type="hidden" name="some-other-name" value="456" />
        <input type="hidden" name="yet-another-name="789" />
</body>
</html>
```

So in these examples I need to get "123" as the answer.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out my mistake and help me get this working. I've spend hours going through the net and all my Google search results are marked as seen :) but still cant get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so you have to use the [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method instead of the `value` property:

```
alert($(data).filter('input[name*="test"]').val());
```

Comment: I just realized your markup is invalid: `<input type="hidden" name="yet-another-name="789" />` is a syntax error. That's probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: oh yeah that's my bad but its not the problem! tested!

Comment: @Amir, strange, it works fine for me in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MAsB/).

Answer (score 0):

I've just replicated your setup and found two problems you need tor resolve to get this to work.

Both are on this line:

```
alert($(data).filter('input[name*="test"]').value);
```

Firstly it should end `.val()`

Secondly, you are asking for a value of a subset. Pick the first match and return the value for that:

```
alert($(data).first('input[name*="test"]').val())
```

Comment: Why would it make no sense? Moreover, why would it make *more* sense to do the exact same thing after adding the markup to the document?

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of multiple matching results but my code will present the same issue. Editing now...

Comment: Tested it again, my setup returns the result. His setup returns 'undefined'. Open to suggestions as to why but the above works fine.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, can you give me an example of a "good practice" way of doing this? regards, Amir

Comment: @Chris, that's because the questioner's HTML markup is invalid.

Comment: @Frédéric, defo not the markup, returns undefined regardless. Suspect its to do with the return of filter(). The .first() returns a single matching element which works fine.

Comment: I cant get it to work with .first but .filter works for sure now!

Comment: Thanks for your help Frédéric, I worked a bit more on it but the .first isn't working. I think the problem was me not realizing I'm dealing with a jQuery object.